# What is the difference between request and args in kubernetes resource config?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to set a deployment of containers in Kubernetes. I want the resource utilization to be controlled. I am referring [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#specify-a-memory-request-and-a-memory-limit).

An example config from the docs -

```
resources:
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
      requests:
        memory: "100Mi"
    command: ["stress"]
    args: ["--vm", "1", "--vm-bytes", "150M", "--vm-hang", "1"]
```

But I am not able to clearly understand the differences between `requests` and `args` fields. `limits` is somewhat clear that the container should not be using more than the limit amount of resource.

What purpose does `args` serve exactly. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#specify-a-memory-request-and-a-memory-limit), it is stated that this is the resource the container would start with. Then how is it different from `requests` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes: Understanding resource requests/limits and scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149806/kubernetes-understanding-resource-requests-limits-and-scheduling)

Comment: Thanks @ShaiKatz. But I was more concerned about the subtleties between requests & args. the referenced question talks more about requests & limits and the behavior that follows up the boundary cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: "200Mi"
  requests:
    memory: "100Mi"
```

Resource has request and limit field.
It means minimum 100Mi memory should be allocated to the container and this values is sufficient to run the container. In case of spike in traffic, it can burst memory consumption upto 200Mi. It is kind of upper bound. If it exceeds more than 200Mi the container will get killed/restarted.

Args are being passed to command(stress container) as command line arguments.

[Stress Tool Docs](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/)
[DockerImageForStress](https://hub.docker.com/r/progrium/stress/)

looks like stress is consuming --vm-bytes=150M  memory passed as an arg

I think with the help of stress tool, the docs are trying to indicate the container can consume memory between request and limit values.

Answer (score 0):

Regards the args, since it's the only thing wasn't answered in the duplicated answer:

Args are not related to the resources definition, it just describes which arguments you pass to your docker container on start.

In the case of the example, the image is probably running java code, which and the user decided to pass some arguments related to memory to it.
If the image was using a different image, for example, node, the args could be some arguments to the node code running inside the container.

Hope that it answers your question.

Comment: Do you mean to say that `vm vm-bytes vm-hang` are all Java related arguments? I do not think so if that is the case. I have not seen these arguments in Java.

Comment: Java usually receives similar arguments that why I said that, after further reading, in that case, it's just `stress` command on pure Linux and the corresponding arguments: https://linux.die.net/man/1/stress